# Update decimal numbers when using other local

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-3, localization

I have this Model

```
public class SalesModelView
{
    [Key]
    public int SaleId { get; set; }
    public int ShopId { get; set; }
    public string ShopName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    public DateTime SaleDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Timer")]
    [Range(0, 24)]
    public int Hours { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Salg")]
    public Decimal Sales { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Behandlinger")]
    public Decimal Treatments { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Omsætning")]
    public Decimal Turnover { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Oms./Timer")]
    public Decimal TurnoverHour { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Effektivitet")]
    public Decimal Efficiency { get; set; }
}
```

and in Danish locale a decimal normally shows as `280.800,00`, so `.` as thousands and `,`as decimal place.

My view shows the correct stuff

[image]

But when saving back to my model, I get the `.` as a decimal separator, passing all the values to:

[image]

(*[original image for better visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dF1Le.png)*)

So the number `546.400` is converted to `546,4`

I already tried **with no luck** to hook up the form submit and replace all `.` with nothing, like

```
$("form").bind("submit", function() {
  $(".number").each(function(){
    var v = $(this).val(v).replace('.','');
    $(this).val(v);
  });
});
```

> **What technique do you guys use for this kinda things?**

P.S. I did read [Hanselman's article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx) but I still got the exact same problems, it's when I pass it to the `Controller` that goes wrong, all is well in the `View`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DefaultModelBinder doesn't work well in these situations. You could write your own or make sure to submit en-US values. Here is an article talking about it.

[Model Binding Decimal Values](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx)